MudNavLink is not active when using onclick
The active class is set on the wrong div on the MudNavLink when using an onclick event (and thus setting the class via code).
I'm using MudBlazor in a .net 8 application and I have created a blazor page that contains a MudNavMenu like this:
<MudNavMenu>
    <MudNavLink OnClick="@(e => ToggleActiveSection("Profile"))" Class="@($"{(ActiveSection == "Profile" ? "active" : "")}")">Profile</MudNavLink>
    <MudNavLink OnClick="@(e => ToggleActiveSection("Security"))" Class="@($"{(ActiveSection == "Security" ? "active" : "")}")">Security</MudNavLink>
</MudNavMenu>

The ToggleActiveSection renders a component in the page depending on the MudNavLink clicked (
<Profile /> or <Security />. It also sets the property ActiveSection. This works fine. Accept for displaying the active link. When I look at the code in my browser, I notice that active is not set to the correct div:

It is set to the div with "mud-nav-item" instead of "mud-nav-link". When I change this in the browser, the active link shows up on my screen.
Am I doing something wrong?

Perhaps this is not the best answer, but I'm facing the same problem and after a lot of searching for a possible solution, I ended up placing the onclick on a div while keeping the use of MudNavLink with the Href.
Razor Code:
<MudNavGroup Title="@Lang["Reports"]" Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Payments" @onclick="@(()=> LoadMenuOptions("payment"))">
    @if (_isReportGroupLoading)
    {
        <MudProgressLinear Color="Color.Primary" Indeterminate="true" />
    }

    @foreach (var group in _reportGroups)
    {
        <MudNavGroup Title="@group.Name" Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Folder" @onclick="@(()=> LoadMenuOptions(group.Name!))">
            @if (_isReportMasterLoading)
            {
                <MudProgressLinear Color="Color.Primary" Indeterminate="true" />
            }
            @foreach (var report in _reportMasters.Where(r => r.ReportGroupKey == group.ReportGroupKey))
            {
                <div onclick="@(() => GoToReport(report))">
                    <MudNavLink Href="@($"{AppRoute.Report}/{report.Id}")" Icon="@Icons.Custom.FileFormats.FileDocument" IconColor="Color.Surface">
                        @report.Name
                    </MudNavLink>
                </div>
            }
        </MudNavGroup>
    }
</MudNavGroup>

C# Code
private void GoToReport(ReportMaster report)
{
    DataSvc.Report = report;
}

In my case, I also had issues with the MudDrawer not closing automatically, and I was closing it programmatically. But after doing this, it closed automatically as well. Ideally, the OnClick of the component would work, but for now, this was the best solution I found. I hope this helps you.

